# How to create fade in/out animations in UINavigationItem titleView?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationitem

I want create titleView animations like iOS Music app! In iOS Music app you can see cool animations. When you select artists or albums from your My Music ( for example ) and then scroll them to the up you can see fade in animation appears on UINavigationBar and also disappears when you are back to the original position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIView.transitionWithView to do an animation. In this case, fading the word ipsum into green:

```
let rangeOfText = (textViewForPlayer.text as NSString).rangeOfString("ipsum", options: nil)
let stringForPlayer = textViewForPlayer.attributedText.mutableCopy() as NSMutableAttributedString

UIView.transitionWithView(self.textViewForPlayer, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
    stringForPlayer.addAttribute(
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
        value: UIColor.greenColor(),
        range: rangeOfText)
    self.textViewForPlayer.attributedText = stringForPlayer
    }, completion: nil)
```

You can use UIView.transitionWithView to do an animation. In this case, fading the word ipsum into green:

```
let rangeOfText = (textViewForPlayer.text as NSString).rangeOfString("ipsum", options: nil)
let stringForPlayer = textViewForPlayer.attributedText.mutableCopy() as NSMutableAttributedString

UIView.transitionWithView(self.textViewForPlayer, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
    stringForPlayer.addAttribute(
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
        value: UIColor.greenColor(),
        range: rangeOfText)
    self.textViewForPlayer.attributedText = stringForPlayer
    }, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, that's remarkably simple.

To have the text shrink and grow during this animation is a whole different ball of wax because simple attempts to change the size of the text will cause the rest of the text view to be re laid out, which I am sure is not your intent.

In that case, I might take a snapshot of that portion of the text view, lay that snapshot over the text view, animate the resizing and transformation. And all of that assumes that what you're transforming it to at the end of the animation is exactly the same size as it was before (otherwise you have a complicated question of what to do with the rest of the text during the animation).

This is going to be a lot of work to achieve a particular animation. I'd ask whether you could accomplish the desired effect more simply other ways (e.g. nested animations, one that fades the text color to clear and then fade it to the new color making it achieve a bit of the "disappear and reappear" feel). That makes the transformation more notable while not getting lost in a rats nest of animation code.

You can use UIView.transitionWithView to do an animation. In this case, fading the word ipsum into green:

```
let rangeOfText = (textViewForPlayer.text as NSString).rangeOfString("ipsum", options: nil)

let stringForPlayer = textViewForPlayer.attributedText.mutableCopy() as NSMutableAttributedString


UIView.transitionWithView(self.textViewForPlayer, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: 
{ () -> Void in
    stringForPlayer.addAttribute(
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,

        value: UIColor.greenColor(),

        range: rangeOfText)
    self.textViewForPlayer.attributedText = stringForPlayer
    }, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, that's remarkably simple.

To have the text shrink and grow during this animation is a whole different ball of wax because simple attempts to change the size of the text will cause the rest of the text view to be re laid out, which I am sure is not your intent.

In that case, I might take a snapshot of that portion of the text view, lay that snapshot over the text view, animate the resizing and transformation. And all of that assumes that what you're transforming it to at the end of the animation is exactly the same size as it was before (otherwise you have a complicated question of what to do with the rest of the text during the animation).

This is going to be a lot of work to achieve a particular animation. I'd ask whether you could accomplish the desired effect more simply other ways (e.g. nested animations, one that fades the text color to clear and then fade it to the new color making it achieve a bit of the "disappear and reappear" feel). That makes the transformation more notable while not getting lost in a rats nest of animation code.

If you wanted to fade it to clearColor before fading it to the desired color (making it "pop" a little more), you could use the completion block:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.textViewForPlayer, duration: 0.25, options: 
.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in

    stringForPlayer.addAttribute(

        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,

        value: UIColor.clearColor(),

        range: rangeOfText)

    self.textViewForPlayer.attributedText = stringForPlayer

    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

        UIView.transitionWithView(self.textViewForPlayer, duration: 0.25,
 options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in

            stringForPlayer.addAttribute(

                NSForegroundColorAttributeName,

                value: UIColor.greenColor(),

                range: rangeOfText)

            self.textViewForPlayer.attributedText = stringForPlayer

            }, completion: nil)
})
```